# replace backslash in str_replace

Tags: php, replace, str-replace, backslash

I have the following string:

`$text = 'Some slash\'s';`

Here is my string replacement:

`$text = str_replace('\'','\\\'',$text);`

What I want to end up with is:

`$text = 'Some slash\\\'s';`

I think Im doing something wrong.

Comment: Backslash craziness: `$text = str_replace('\'',"\\\\\\'",$text);`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Why not posting as an answer?

Comment: @AmalMurali Agree. It works perfectly. Get the credit you deserve!

Comment: @jkushner Sure. Posted an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but I think the following should work:

```
$text = str_replace('\'', "\\\\\\'", $text);
```